# Indented table borders

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on turning a normal html table like so:

[image: original]

into and indented version as follows:

[image]

Even if I can't set this in html someone might know of a way in which I can hide the initial part of the border to match the start of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several bad ways to do this, I'm sure. You'll just have to get creative.

Here is one example to do this, with some classes, empty table cells and colspans:
http://jsfiddle.net/ESFuC/

Comment: In the end I ended up using this solution. I like the fact that if the text doesn't fit in the indented cell this option will automatically resize the cell. Further to that the borders line up perfectly.

Comment: visually fine, not so much for accessibility. Screen-readers will throw off visually impaired users with empty table cells and row/column counts.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by playing about with the table cells and taking advantage of `display:inline-block;` there are other ways to achieve this but this should work across most browsers.

[Fiddle with demo](http://jsfiddle.net/27VEb/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with divs inside cells like this;

http://jsfiddle.net/UdF98/

I colored the bottom line red, seems fine except the one at the bottom. Maybe you can modify to suit your needs.

Comment: Bit hacky but seems to do the job!

Comment: Yeah, maybe using <h#> tags instead of divs will be better for SEO. And check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/UdF98/1/) out, why not use different colors for different indents :D